# pyodbc: Memory Error using fast_executemany with TEXT / NTEXT columns

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I'm having an issue with inserting rows into a database. Just wondering if anyone has any ideas why this is happening? It works when I avoid using fast_executemany but then inserts become very slow.

```
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=' + driver + ';SERVER=' + server+ \
                      ';UID=' + user+ ';PWD=' + password)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.fast_executemany = True

insert_sql = """
INSERT INTO table (a, b, c)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
"""

cursor.executemany(insert_sql, insert_params)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e7e82e4d8c2d> in <module>
      2 start_time = time.time()
      3 
----> 4 cursor.executemany(insert_sql, insert_params)

MemoryError:
```

Comment: By chance are you running this Python code on a Linux machine? If so, what distribution/environment is it?

Comment: What version of pyodbc are you using?

Comment: @GordThompson I'm running it on Windows 10

Comment: @EdekiOkoh It's using 4.0.25

Comment: Does the table have any `TEXT` or `NTEXT` columns? If so, then [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/547) might be of interest.

Comment: @GordThompson thanks, that was the issue!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a known issue with `fast_executemany` when working with `TEXT` or `NTEXT` columns, as described on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/547).

The problem is that when pyodbc queries the database metadata to determine the maximum size of the column the driver returns 2 GB (instead of 0, as would be returned for a `[n]varchar(max)` column).

pyodbc allocates 2 GB of memory for each `[N]TEXT` element in the parameter array, and the Python app quickly runs out of memory.

The workaround is to use `cursor.setinputsizes([(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR, 0, 0)])` (as described [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/547#issuecomment-482157537)) to coax pyodbc into treating `[N]TEXT` columns like `[n]varchar(max)` columns.

(Given that `[N]TEXT` is a deprecated column type for SQL Server it is unlikely that there will be a formal fix for this issue.)

Answer (score 2):

While this issue was solved for the OP by [Gord Thompson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56007490/2738164), I wanted to note that the question as written applies to other cases where a `MemoryError` may occur, and `fast_executemany` actually can throw that in other circumstances beyond just usage of `[N]TEXT` columns.

In my case a `MemoryError` was thrown during an attempt to `INSERT` several million records at once, and as [noted here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fast_executemany), "parameter values are held in memory, so very large numbers of records (tens of millions or more) may cause memory issues".  It doesn't necessarily require tens of millions to trigger, so YMMV.

An easy solution to this is to identify a sane number of records to batch per each execute.  Here's an example if using a Pandas dataframe as a source (establish your `insert_query` as usual):

```
batch_size = 5000  # Set to a desirable batch size
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    try:
        cursor.fast_executemany = True

        # Iterate each batch chunk using numpy's split
        for chunk in np.array_split(df, batch_size):
            cursor.executemany(insert_query,
                               chunk.values.tolist())

        # Run a single commit at the end of the transaction
        connection.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        # Rollback on any exception
        connection.rollback()
        raise e
```

Hope this helps anyone who hits this issue and *doesn't* have any `[N]TEXT` columns on their target!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the MemoryError was because I was using a very old driver 'SQL Server'. Switched to the newer driver ('ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server') as described in the link below and it worked:
[link](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/474#issuecomment-432730100)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).